# Long-click jQuery plugin for dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dynamic-content

I've written a plugin to create *long click* event handler for my web application. I know it is not too advanced and that it has low functionality, but I am trying to improve it. You can see my plugin below:

```js
$(function($) {
  var holdTimer;
  var timerRunning = false;
  $.fn.longClick = function(handler, time) {
    if (time == undefined) time = 500;
    return this.on({
      mouseup: function() {
        clearTimeout(holdTimer);
        timerRunning = false;
      },
      mousedown: function() {
        var self = this;
        timerRunning = true;
        holdTimer = window.setTimeout(function() {
          handler.call(self)
        }, time);
      }
    })
  };
  $.fn.longClick.defaultTime = 500;
}(jQuery));
```

**What is my problem?**

I am in the situation of putting Ajax-generated content on my page, and you can easily know that `.longClick()` won't work anymore for those elements.

I have the following snippet:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/ajax/",
  type: "POST", 
  data: {
    action: "load-posts",
  },
  dataType: "html",
  success: function(data) {
    $(".profile-wrapper").append(data);
  }
});
```

The `data` looks like this:

```
<div class="post">
  <div class="comments">Comments</div>
</div>
```

Then I need to use the `.longClick` event for `.comments`. I found this, on Stack Overflow, and I know which my situation is, but I don't know how to modify my plugin to work like `$(selector).on(event,childSelector,data,function)`.

**How would you modify this plugin to work on dynamic content?** Thank you for your patience and help.

### EDIT FOR @AminJafari

The long-click event now fires, but inside the function, the `.post` seems to be `undefined`:

```
$(".profile-wrapper .tabs-wrapper .tab .post").longClick(function () {
  var $post = $(this);
  var menuTop = $post.offset().top + "px";
  // ...
}
```

Output from the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED:**

```
$(function($) {
  var holdTimer;
  var timerRunning = false;
  $.fn.longClick = function(handler, time) {
    if (time == undefined) time = 500;
    var that=$(this);
    $(document).on('mouseup',that,function(){
        clearTimeout(holdTimer);
        timerRunning = false;
      });
    $(document).on('mousedown',that,function(){
        var self = this;
        timerRunning = true;
        holdTimer = window.setTimeout(function() {
          handler.call(self)
        }, time);
     });
  };
  $.fn.longClick.defaultTime = 500;
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: are you trying to use `longClick()` on all of those elements or is this the way they're structured?

Comment: The structure is `.profile-wrapper > .tabs-wrapper > .tab > .post`.

Comment: can you share your html as well please? also check out the output of `alert($('.profile-wrapper > .tabs-wrapper > .tab > .post').length);`

Comment: Is there any way we can start a chat room here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62033/discussion-between-amin-jafari-and-victor).